# Seeing the invisible の in old names and words

Tags: kanji, readings

In many place and people names, there is an "invisible の", e.g., 三宮 is read さん**の**みや and 中大兄皇子 is なか**の**おおえ**の**おうじ.  This can also happen in words: 班田収授法 is read はんでんしゅうじゅ**の**ほう, which I am less comfortable with because I suppose if it were modern Japanese it would be read without the の.

As I recall, this is because の was originally not written in 漢字 in olden days, so not all the phonetics were captured in writing (to the extent that phonetics were captured in 漢字).  My question is: could someone in olden days know or reasonably guess such readings without having specifically learned these names/words?  If so, can anyone explain what the basic rules/guidelines are?  (You can restrict this question to being about insertion of の's, but I would be happy to hear about other aspects as well.)

Comment: Related:  [Why did の disappear from 山手, but in 御茶ノ水 it's in katakana?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2931/78).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Out of interest, I did some statistics... see below for the resultng data.

## How I generated the data:

- kanji + readings taken from (a) ZIP codes place names, (b) jmdict, (c) wikipedia articles
- matched each kanji to a part of the reading by iterating over all possibilties for each kanji's reading in kanjidict and jmdict
- any の remaining that cannot be matched to a kanji is an "invisible の"

Then I analyzed these readings for a list of which words/kanji are often linked with の

## Some notes:

- In total, I managed to collect 9019 words with an invisible の.
- They might not include very old words; or names of smaller villages/rivers/shrines/...
- Automated parsing, there will be some errors. For example, 猪 has got the readings い and いの, thus the の gets classified as an invisible one. I did take a manual look at the data and removed such errors, but I probably did miss some.
- The list below is sorted by the `length` of elements in front and after の, `length` is the number of elements into which the kanjis have been split: 浦村【うらむら】 is 2, 大人【おとな】 is 1 etc.

## Some observations:

- Overall, this seems to be more common with *kun* readings as opposed to *on* readings.
- Never realized this before, but this happens in the really common word 彼女 as well: 彼【か】の女【じょ】
- の is really common with simple native Japanese words: の宮, の上・下, の木, の国, の尾, の裏, の郡【こおり】, の内, の島, の森, の御子
- For on-readings, often with place names or personal names etc: の洞院, の関市, の木町, の関町, の神社, の小路通, の黒麻呂
- の法 occurs three times in the data set
- In front of の, some common elements are 藤原, 大中臣, 菅原, 宇都, 安倍, 宮野, 大江.

## Wordlist

For reference, a list of the words [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/FfA4Uqhz).

## The resulting data:

Don't view this on the mobile version...

## Afterwards, ...のX

**Length 1**

- のX　　　みや： 842 (宮)
- のX　　　うえ： 736 (上)
- のX　　　　き： 261 (木²³⁶・樹⁴・棊¹・吉²・貴²・城⁹・嬉¹・紀²・岐¹・喜²・帰¹)
- のX　　　かみ： 247 (上¹⁵・守⁵³・神¹⁶⁹・頭⁷・侍²・髪¹)
- のX　　　くに： 241 (国²³¹・國⁵・邦⁵)
- のX　　　した： 229 (下²²⁸・舌¹)
- のX　　　　お： 193 (尾¹⁰⁵・面⁴⁴・阿²・帯¹・御³・緒²・男⁸・小¹²・烏¹・雄¹³・お¹・生¹)
- のX　　しょう： 188 (荘⁹⁷・庄⁶⁷・彰¹・少⁶・障⁵・請¹・正⁵・娼¹・小³・抄¹・生¹)
- のX　　　　み： 188 (海¹³・実⁸・見¹・御⁷⁷・神⁴・躬²・美⁴・皇⁴³・満⁶・光²⁰・三⁸・巳¹・弥¹)
- のX　　　　へ： 183 (戸)
- のX　　　うら： 147 (浦¹⁴⁶・裏¹)
- のX　　　もと： 137 (本¹⁰⁶・元¹²・基¹⁸・下¹)
- のX　　こおり： 136 (郡)
- のX　　　こう： 132 (甲³・小¹²²・河²・神¹・更¹・幸¹・巷²)
- のX　　　せき： 124 (関¹²¹・夕²・席¹)
- のX　　　うち： 124 (内¹²¹・中²・打¹)
- のX　　　しま： 112 (島¹⁰⁴・嶋⁵・洲³)
- のX　　　　や： 095 (谷⁶³・屋²⁷・八¹・矢³・夜¹)
- のX　　　みち： 092 (道⁸²・通¹⁰)
- のX　　　とう： 085 (洞⁶⁸・塔¹¹・党¹・東²・頭²・登¹)
- のX　　　　す： 076 (巣⁴⁹・栖⁶・洲¹⁶・主¹・菅³・須¹)
- のX　　　もり： 072 (森⁴⁷・守³・盛¹⁹・杜³)
- のX　　　おお： 072 (大⁷⁰・邑¹・多¹)
- のX　　　よし： 072 (義³¹・好³・良²¹・嘉¹・淑³・吉⁴・善⁷・慶¹・宜¹)
- のX　　　だて： 066 (館)
- のX　　　　わ： 064 (輪⁶²・和²)
- のX　　　　こ： 064 (児³・子³⁷・粉²・古⁹・河²・国¹・小⁵・木¹・高¹・巨¹・己¹・湖¹)
- のX　　　すけ： 063 (介¹⁶・亮⁶・輔⁶・資¹³・助¹¹・佐⁸・祐¹・相²)
- のX　　　　せ： 061 (瀬⁶⁰・背¹)
- のX　　　じょ： 060 (女)
- のX　　　　べ： 058 (部²⁸・辺²⁷・戸³)
- のX　　　まき： 055 (牧¹²・巻⁴³)
- のX　　　　ま： 054 (澗¹・勾¹・曲¹・間⁹・真³⁰・麻⁹・目¹・馬²)
- のX　　　はま： 052 (浜⁵¹・濱¹)
- のX　　じょう： 052 (城⁴⁰・丞²・尉⁶・常¹・允¹・掾¹・上¹)
- のX　　　やま： 051 (山)
- のX　　　　え： 050 (江³⁵・吉⁶・枝²・永⁵・会¹・兄¹)
- のX　　　いけ： 049 (池)
- のX　　　　め： 049 (目⁴⁴・売²・眼¹・妻²)
- のX　　　まさ： 048 (将⁸・正¹³・雅¹⁴・当⁶・方¹・理¹・匡¹・政⁴)
- のX　　つぼね： 048 (局)
- のX　　　くち： 047 (口)
- のX　くにのみやつこ： 047 (国造)
- のX　　　たか： 047 (高²⁵・隆¹⁵・孝³・鷹⁴)
- のX　　　より： 046 (頼⁴⁵・自¹)
- のX　　　　い： 045 (井³⁰・居¹・胆²・去²・忌¹・威¹・五十¹・苡¹・伊²・猪¹・五¹・懿¹・出¹)
- のX　　　はら： 045 (原)
- のX　　　なが： 045 (長²⁸・永¹⁶・脩¹)
- のX　　　ただ： 043 (忠³⁶・斉³・縄²・三¹・直¹)
- のX　　　ひろ： 042 (広³⁷・博¹・弘³・寛¹)
- のX　　　ばん： 042 (馬³⁸・番³・晩¹)
- のX　　　もろ： 040 (師³³・諸⁷)
- のX　　　きよ： 040 (清³¹・浄⁶・潔²・聖¹)
- のX　　　　か： 040 (日¹⁵・替¹・香¹⁰・花²・嘉¹・迦¹・鹿¹・蚊¹・箇¹・訶¹・冠¹・夏¹・上¹・賀²・歌¹)
- のX　　　つね： 039 (経²⁷・常⁹・恒³)
- のX　　　やす： 038 (泰⁷・靖¹・康⁴・安¹⁵・保¹¹)
- のX　　　いん： 038 (院³³・印²・胤¹・尹¹・因¹)
- のX　　ちょう： 037 (町²⁴・丁¹・長⁷・庁⁴・超¹)
- のX　　　さき： 037 (崎³¹・埼³・前²・咲¹)
- のX　　　これ： 034 (惟¹⁰・維⁹・是⁶・伊⁹)
- のX　みささぎ： 034 (陵)
- のX　　　かわ： 033 (川²⁷・河⁶)
- のX　　　さだ： 033 (定¹⁴・貞¹⁹)
- のX　　　ため： 033 (為)
- のX　　　あき： 032 (明⁴・彰¹・顕²¹・秋⁵・昭¹)
- のX　　　　ぶ： 032 (夫²⁴・部²・武³・敷³)
- のX　　　むね： 030 (宗²⁵・棟⁵)
- のX　　　あり： 030 (有²⁶・在⁴)
- のX　　　なか： 029 (仲²⁰・中⁹)
- のX　　みこと： 029 (尊)
- のX　　　かね： 029 (兼²²・金³・鐘²・懐²)
- のX　　　いえ： 029 (家)
- のX　　　たに： 029 (谷)
- のX　　　うみ： 028 (海²³・湖⁵)
- のX　　　だい： 027 (台¹¹・大¹³・第²・内¹)
- のX　　　ちか： 027 (親²³・近⁴)
- のX　　　なり： 027 (業³・成²¹・済¹・生¹・形¹)
- のX　　　しげ： 027 (滋²・重¹⁸・繁³・成³・茂¹)
- のX　おおきみ： 027 (王²⁶・大王¹)
- のX　　　おか： 027 (岡¹⁹・丘⁶・崗¹・岳¹)
- のX　　　こし： 026 (越³・腰²³)
- のX　　　すく： 026 (宿²⁵・少¹)
- のX　　　　は： 026 (葉¹⁵・波³・羽⁵・長³)
- のX　　　みね： 025 (峰⁹・峯⁹・嶺²・岑⁵)
- のX　　　きみ： 025 (公¹⁰・君¹⁵)
- のX　　　とし： 025 (俊¹⁴・歳¹・年⁴・利³・敏²・稔¹)
- のX　　　すえ： 024 (末⁴・季¹⁹・陶¹)
- のX　　　のり： 024 (範⁹・教⁶・則⁵・経¹・憲²・義¹)
- のX　　　とき： 024 (時²³・説¹)
- のX　　　そう： 024 (草⁹・宗⁶・匝²・僧¹・荘¹・奏⁴・諍¹)
- のX　　　くら： 024 (倉²²・蔵¹・鞍¹)
- のX　　　また： 024 (俣¹³・股³・又⁸)
- のX　　　とも： 024 (知¹⁰・友⁴・倫¹・朝⁴・具¹・智¹・奉²・誠¹)
- のX　　　むら： 024 (邑⁸・叢²・村¹⁴)
- のX　　　さね： 024 (実²¹・真³)
- のX　　　のぶ： 024 (信¹⁵・宣⁴・順¹・陳²・惟²)
- のX　　　ごう： 023 (郷)
- のX　　　　ご： 021 (御¹⁴・五⁶・語¹)
- のX　　　はな： 021 (鼻⁵・花¹⁵・華¹)
- のX　　　まち： 020 (町)
- のX　　　たき： 020 (滝)
- のX　　　くま： 020 (熊⁶・隈¹⁴)
- のX　　　はる： 019 (春¹⁷・玄¹・晴¹)
- のX　　　いわ： 019 (岩⁷・磐²・石¹⁰)
- のX　　　さと： 018 (里¹³・郷⁵)
- のX　　　うじ： 018 (氏)
- のX　　　　り： 017 (り²・里¹⁴・離¹)
- のX　　　　ひ： 017 (秘¹・比³・日⁴・碑⁴・火²・非¹・毘¹・斐¹)
- のX　　　まえ： 016 (前)
- のX　　　ない： 016 (内)
- のX　　　　た： 016 (太³・大²・手²・田⁵・多⁴)
- のX　　　　だ： 016 (田⁴・太¹¹・多¹)
- のX　　　きん： 015 (近¹・公¹³・琴¹)
- のX　　　しろ： 015 (代⁷・白⁶・城²)
- のX　　　　し： 015 (シ¹・四⁴・始¹・史²・志³・次¹・し¹・磯¹・資¹)
- のX　　　おう： 015 (王¹¹・皇⁴)
- のX　　　　つ： 015 (津)
- のX　　　　で： 015 (出)
- のX　　　ひら： 015 (平¹³・枚²)
- のX　　　ぼう： 015 (坊)
- のX　　　たな： 014 (棚¹²・店²)
- のX　　　ほう： 014 (方¹・法³・袍⁴・宝¹・芳¹・奉²・放¹・保¹)
- のX　　まつり： 013 (祭)
- のX　　　とよ： 013 (豊)
- のX　　　　と： 013 (戸³・渡³・と¹・止¹・利¹・門¹・頭¹・刀¹・十¹)
- のX　　　はし： 013 (橋¹⁰・嘴²・觜¹)
- のX　　むらじ： 012 (連)
- のX　　　あさ： 012 (朝¹¹・浅¹)
- のX　　　ゆき： 012 (行)
- のX　　　　う： 012 (生⁵・御²・宇³・右¹・卯¹)
- のX　　　　ね： 012 (根¹⁰・音¹・禰¹)
- のX　　　あま： 012 (海²・天¹・尼⁸・海人¹)
- のX　　つかさ： 012 (司)
- のX　　　たけ： 012 (岳²・武⁹・猛¹)
- のX　　　まつ： 011 (松)
- のX　　　わき： 011 (脇)
- のX　　　さか： 011 (阪¹・坂⁷・逆²・酒¹)
- のX　　　しん： 011 (新⁷・進¹・神¹・親¹・信¹)
- のX　　　いち： 011 (市⁴・一⁷)
- のX　　　ふみ： 011 (文)
- のX　　やしろ： 011 (社)
- のX　　　　て： 011 (手)
- のX　　　どう： 010 (道⁸・堂¹・童¹)
- のX　　　はか： 010 (墓)
- のX　　　かげ： 010 (景⁹・影¹)
- のX　　　しり： 010 (尻)
- のX　　　くぼ： 010 (窪)
- のX　　　さん： 010 (三)
- のX　　　うた： 010 (歌)
- のX　　　じん： 010 (神⁶・陣³・尽¹)

**Length 2**

- のX　　　　　　こうじ： 123 (小路¹²²・河内¹)
- のX　　　　　　みやし： 078 (宮市⁶⁹・宮氏⁵・宮師¹・宮仕¹・宮四¹・宮し¹)
- のX　　　　みやちょう： 073 (宮町)
- のX　　　　　とういん： 068 (洞院)
- のX　　　　　　くにの： 067 (国の⁶⁵・国²)
- のX　　　　　だてまち： 056 (館町)
- のX　　　　　　　みこ： 048 (御子²・神子³・皇子⁴³)
- のX　　　　　うえまさ： 048 (上正³³・上政⁵・上雅⁸・上将²)
- のX　　　　　　ばんば： 038 (馬場)
- のX　　　　　みやじん： 033 (宮神)
- のX　　　　　　　へし： 032 (戸市²⁵・戸氏⁶・戸試¹)
- のX　　　　　みやえき： 029 (宮駅)
- のX　　　　　　みかど： 029 (御門)
- のX　　　　　したとし： 028 (下利¹⁴・下俊¹²・下淑¹・下敏¹)
- のX　　　　　　　みつ： 027 (満⁶・光²⁰・美都¹)
- のX　　　　　　せきし： 026 (関市²⁵・関シ¹)
- のX　　　　　おおかみ： 024 (大神)
- のX　　　　　うえよし： 023 (上義⁸・上芳²・上喜¹・上嘉²・上良⁴・上佳²・上善¹・上由¹・上吉¹・上理¹)
- のX　　　　　　うえの： 021 (上の²・上¹⁹)
- のX　　　　　　すくね： 021 (宿禰²⁰・宿祢¹)
- のX　　　　　うえこう： 021 (上滉¹・上公⁵・上康¹・上高¹・上晃³・上光¹・上紘¹・上幸³・上浩²・上好¹・上孝¹・上紅¹)
- のX　　　　　　みちし： 020 (道市)
- のX　　　　　うえかず： 019 (上和¹²・上一⁷)
- のX　　　　　　　おし： 019 (面市)
- のX　　　　　　　べの： 017 (部¹⁵・辺¹・辺の¹)
- のX　　　　　うえしん： 017 (上信⁴・上真⁴・上慎³・上伸²・上心¹・上親¹・上眞¹・上秦¹)
- のX　　　　　きちょう： 016 (木町)
- のX　　　　うえしょう： 015 (上章²・上小⁴・上昭¹・上正²・上頌¹・上庄¹・上翔¹・上昌²・上尚¹)
- のX　　　　せきちょう： 015 (関町)
- のX　　　　　うえひろ： 015 (上博⁷・上弘²・上宏¹・上寛²・上裕²・上浩¹)
- のX　　　　　いんみち： 015 (院通)
- のX　　　　　　うえま： 014 (上真⁶・上ま²・上麻⁴・上マ²)
- のX　　　　みやちゅう： 014 (宮中¹¹・宮駐²・宮忠¹)
- のX　　　　　うえたか： 014 (上堯²・上孝²・上隆⁵・上貴³・上高¹・上崇¹)
- のX　　　　　　きまさ： 013 (木正)
- のX　　　しょうちょう： 013 (庄町)
- のX　　　　　じょうし： 013 (城市¹¹・城志¹・上子¹)
- のX　　　　　みやくに： 013 (宮国¹・宮邦¹²)
- のX　　　　　　うえみ： 012 (上光³・上美⁶・上み²・上満¹)
- のX　　　　　うえゆう： 012 (上雄²・上祐³・上優¹・上裕⁴・上侑¹・上宥¹)
- のX　　　　　うえよう： 012 (上陽³・上瑤¹・上洋³・上庸²・上幼²・上瑶¹)
- のX　　　　　みやさだ： 012 (宮貞¹¹・宮定¹)
- のX　　　　　うえひで： 011 (上英⁵・上秀⁶)
- のX　　　　　みやひろ： 011 (宮広¹・宮博⁶・宮洋¹・宮宏²・宮弘¹)
- のX　　　　　うえやす： 011 (上泰⁴・上安⁴・上保¹・上康²)
- のX　　　　　　まきし： 011 (巻市)
- のX　　　　　うらえき： 011 (浦駅)
- のX　　　　　　ないし： 010 (内侍)
- のX　　　　　　うえゆ： 010 (上由⁴・上ゆ²・上優²・上裕¹・上ユ¹)
- のX　　　　　うえかつ： 010 (上克³・上勝⁷)
- のX　　　　　　そうし： 010 (草子³・草紙⁶・宗子¹)
- のX　　　　みやしょう： 010 (宮小⁷・宮商¹・宮章¹・宮精¹)
- のX　　　　　みやけい： 010 (宮競³・宮敬²・宮警³・宮涬¹・宮慶¹)
- のX　　　　さきちょう： 010 (崎町)
- のX　　　　　うらまち： 010 (浦町)
- のX　　　　　　みたま： 010 (御魂)
- のX　　　　　　みやき： 010 (宮記⁹・宮基¹)
- のX　　　　　みやよし： 009 (宮宜¹・宮好¹・宮圭¹・宮嘉¹・宮義²・宮芳¹・宮善²)
- のX　　　　　　　すし： 009 (巣市⁸・主市¹)
- のX　　　　　　　まろ： 009 (麻呂⁸・麻路¹)
- のX　　　　　　へえき： 009 (戸駅)
- のX　　　　　　やまし： 009 (山市)
- のX　　　　　　　やし： 009 (屋市⁷・谷氏²)
- のX　　　　　　くにふ： 009 (国風)
- のX　　　　　みやゆう： 009 (宮優²・宮郵⁷)
- のX　　　　　えちょう： 009 (江町)
- のX　　　　　うえとし： 009 (上敏³・上寿¹・上俊³・上鋭¹・上利¹)
- のX　　　　みやじょう： 009 (宮城⁷・宮定¹・宮常¹)
- のX　　　　　　きむら： 009 (木村)
- のX　　　　　こしまさ： 008 (腰正)
- のX　　　　　したひろ： 008 (下博⁴・下裕²・下浩²)
- のX　　　　たなどおり： 008 (棚通)
- のX　　　　　うえけん： 008 (上謙³・上健²・上堅¹・上賢¹・上憲¹)
- のX　　　　いけちょう： 008 (池町)
- のX　　　　　うえとも： 008 (上知³・上智⁴・上朋¹)
- のX　　　　うえしゅん： 008 (上春⁴・上俊⁴)
- のX　　　　　みやまさ： 008 (宮雅¹・宮正⁶・宮政¹)
- のX　　　　　　うえち： 008 (上智³・上千²・上知¹・上地²)
- のX　　　　　　かまち： 008 (日町)
- のX　　　　　　へまち： 008 (戸町)
- のX　　　　　うえなお： 008 (上直⁴・上尚⁴)
- のX　　　　　　ごしょ： 008 (御所)
- のX　　　　　みくりや： 008 (御厨)
- のX　　　　　うえまち： 007 (上町)
- のX　　　　　　うえさ： 007 (上サ¹・上佐²・上小¹・上早³)
- のX　　　　　みやむら： 007 (宮村)
- のX　　　　　みやまち： 007 (宮町)
- のX　　　　もりちょう： 007 (森町)
- のX　　　　うえじゅん： 007 (上順¹・上準¹・上純³・上淳²)
- のX　　　　　　かいち： 007 (日市)
- のX　　　　　　　こま： 007 (古麻⁴・子麻²・高麗¹)
- のX　　　　　ひろなり： 007 (広成⁶・広業¹)
- のX　　　　　　　ばば： 007 (馬場)
- のX　　　　　　おおえ： 007 (大兄)
- のX　　　　　　じょの： 007 (女の)
- のX　　　　　　へゆう： 007 (戸郵)
- のX　　　しょうしょう： 007 (少将⁴・荘小¹・庄小²)
- のX　　　　　みややす： 007 (宮鳩¹・宮泰²・宮康³・宮安¹)
- のX　　　　　へちょう： 007 (戸長¹・戸町⁶)
- のX　　　　　　みやさ： 006 (宮沙²・宮さ²・宮詐¹・宮砂¹)
- のX　　　　　　きない： 006 (木内)
- のX　　　　　　きまち： 006 (木町)
- のX　　　　　　　こぎ： 006 (子木⁵・小忌¹)
- のX　　　　　うえけい： 006 (上慶¹・上計¹・上圭²・上敬¹・上恵¹)
- のX　　　　　　みやけ： 006 (宮家⁵・三宅¹)
- のX　　　　　みやかん： 006 (宮環²・宮簡⁴)
- のX　　　　　うえてつ： 006 (上鉄¹・上哲⁵)
- のX　　　　　　きしん： 006 (木新⁵・木伸¹)
- のX　　　　　　やかつ： 006 (谷勝)
- のX　　　　　　みやじ： 006 (宮ジ¹・宮自²・宮寺¹・宮治¹・宮地¹)
- のX　　　　　　やこれ： 006 (谷惟)
- のX　　　　　　いわと： 006 (岩戸⁵・石門¹)
- のX　　　　ちょうじゃ： 006 (長者)
- のX　　　　　　だいぶ： 006 (大夫)
- のX　　　　　　なかつ： 006 (中⁴・仲²)
- のX　　　　　　わむら： 006 (輪村)
- のX　　　　　うえゆき： 006 (上雪²・上行¹・上幸²・上之¹)
- のX　　　　　うえたつ： 006 (上達⁴・上竜¹・上辰¹)
- のX　　　　　　　おの： 006 (男之¹・面²・尾の¹・雄¹・雄能¹)
- のX　　　　　　おうじ： 006 (王子²・皇子³・尾氏¹)
- のX　　　　　　　えの： 006 (吉⁵・江¹)
- のX　　　　　　じょた： 006 (女た)
- のX　　　　　じんじゃ： 006 (神社)
- のX　　　　うえりょう： 006 (上亮²・上了¹・上涼²・上龍¹)
- のX　　　　みやひがし： 006 (宮東)
- のX　　　　うらちょう： 006 (浦町)
- のX　　　　　わちょう： 006 (輪町)
- のX　　　　　　せちえ： 006 (節会)
- のX　　　　　したたか： 006 (下隆²・下高²・下尊¹・下貴¹)
- のX　　　　　うえせい： 006 (上製¹・上井¹・上誠²・上清¹・上青¹)
- のX　　　　　もとまさ： 006 (本正²・本雅¹・本政¹・基政¹・元政¹)
- のX　　　　　　せんじ： 006 (宣旨)
- のX　　　　　うえはる： 005 (上春²・上治²・上晴¹)
- のX　　　　　うえそう： 005 (上宗³・上聡¹・上騒¹)
- のX　　　　　　　いし： 005 (威子¹・井氏¹・苡子¹・伊子¹・懿子¹)
- のX　　　　　　　たち： 005 (太刀³・大刀²)
- のX　　　　　　よしこ： 005 (吉子¹・義子¹・良子¹・慶子¹・宜子¹)
- のX　　　　　　　かぐ： 005 (香久²・香具³)
- のX　　　　　みやこう： 005 (宮高³・宮公¹・宮孝¹)
- のX　　　　　　みやま： 005 (宮ま¹・宮真²・宮麻²)
- のX　　　　　　へぐん： 005 (戸郡)
- のX　　　　　みやなお： 005 (宮直⁴・宮尚¹)
- のX　　　　くちちょう： 005 (口町)
- のX　　　　　　すえき： 005 (巣駅)
- のX　　　　　べちょう： 005 (辺町⁴・部丁¹)
- のX　　　　はまちょう： 005 (浜町⁴・浜丁¹)
- のX　　　　もとちょう： 005 (本町³・元町²)
- のX　　　　したちょう： 005 (下町)
- のX　　　　　うえたく： 005 (上琢²・上卓³)
- のX　　　　　へじょう： 005 (戸城)
- のX　　　　　　　きし： 005 (吉士¹・貴子²・嬉子¹・木氏¹)
- のX　　　　　したこう： 005 (下航¹・下浩¹・下康²・下広¹)
- のX　　　　　　　へば： 005 (戸バ)
- のX　　　　　したよし： 005 (下善¹・下好¹・下芳¹・下吉¹・下淑¹)
- のX　　　　　うらむら： 005 (浦村)
- のX　　　　　　へけい： 005 (戸警)
- のX　　　　　　やすま： 005 (安万¹・安麻³・安萬¹)
- のX　　　　　　　せと： 005 (瀬戸⁴・瀬ト¹)
- のX　　　　　みやつね： 005 (宮恒⁴・宮常¹)
- のX　　　　　みやたか： 005 (宮尊¹・宮崇¹・宮孝¹・宮隆¹・宮貴¹)
- のX　　　　　　うえじ： 005 (上二¹・上ジ²・上次¹・上治¹)
- のX　　　　　　うえし： 005 (上四²・上詩¹・上氏¹・上士¹)
- のX　　　　　　すくな： 005 (宿那¹・宿奈²・少名¹・宿儺¹)
- のX　　　　　　みくら： 005 (御倉)
- のX　　　　　つちょう： 005 (津町)
- のX　　　　　　　えら： 005 (永良)
- のX　　　　　　いんの： 005 (院)
- のX　　　　　うらごう： 005 (浦郷⁴・浦河¹)
- のX　　　　　しょうじ： 005 (障子)
- のX　　　　　まきこう： 005 (巻港⁴・巻高¹)
- のX　　　　　はまえき： 005 (浜駅)
- のX　　　　うえあきら： 005 (上鑑¹・上明¹・上旭¹・上昭¹・上章¹)

**Length 3**

- のX　　　　　　　　くにのしき： 063 (国の式)
- のX　　　　　　　　みやしりつ： 049 (宮市立)
- のX　　　　　　　こうじどおり： 040 (小路通)
- のX　　　　　　　みやじんじゃ： 032 (宮神社)
- のX　　　　　　　こうじひがし： 024 (小路東)
- のX　　　　　　とういんどおり： 022 (洞院通)
- のX　　　　　　　　こうじにし： 021 (小路西)
- のX　　　　　　とういんひがし： 018 (洞院東)
- のX　　　　　　　　　おしりつ： 017 (面市立)
- のX　　　　　　　　みちしりつ： 016 (道市立)
- のX　　　　　　　とういんにし： 016 (洞院西)
- のX　　　　　　　ばんばどおり： 015 (馬場通)
- のX　　　　　　　　　へしりつ： 012 (戸市立)
- のX　　　　　　　　せきしりつ： 011 (関市立)
- のX　　　　　　　ばんばひがし： 010 (馬場東)
- のX　　　　　　　　　くにふど： 009 (国風土)
- のX　　　　　　　　　こうじさ： 008 (小路下)
- のX　　　　　　　　ばんばにし： 008 (馬場西)
- のX　　　　　　　　みやきねん： 008 (宮記念)
- のX　　　　　　とういんちょう： 007 (洞院町)
- のX　　　　みやしょうがっこう： 007 (宮小学校)
- のX　　　　　　　　みかどつね： 007 (御門経)
- のX　　　　　　　　へゆうびん： 007 (戸郵便)
- のX　　　　　　　こうじちょう： 007 (小路町)
- のX　　　　　　　　まきしりつ： 007 (巻市立)
- のX　　　　　　　みやゆうびん： 007 (宮郵便)
- のX　　　　　　　へちょうりつ： 006 (戸町立)
- のX　　　　　　　　うえよしお： 006 (上芳雄¹・上善夫¹・上義雄¹・上義夫¹・上良雄¹・上義朗¹)
- のX　　　　　　　　　じょたち： 006 (女たち)
- のX　　　　　　　だてまちにし： 006 (館町西)
- のX　　　　　　　　やましりつ： 006 (山市立)
- のX　　　　　　　　うえけんじ： 006 (上謙二¹・上健司¹・上堅二¹・上謙治¹・上賢嗣¹・上憲氏¹)
- のX　　　　　　　じょうしりつ： 006 (城市立)
- のX　　　　　　　　　すしりつ： 006 (巣市立)
- のX　　　　みやちゅうがっこう： 006 (宮中学校)
- のX　　　　　　　　みかどのぶ： 006 (御門信)
- のX　　　　　　　　　おおえの： 006 (大兄)
- のX　　　　　　　うえしんいち： 005 (上伸一¹・上親一¹・上眞一¹・上信一¹・上慎一¹)
- のX　　　　　　　　　　こまろ： 005 (古麻呂³・子麻呂²)
- のX　　　　　　　うえまさのり： 005 (上正紀¹・上正矩¹・上正賀¹・上将憲¹・上正憲¹)
- のX　　　　　　　　　　へばい： 005 (戸バイ)
- のX　　　　　　　　へけいさつ： 005 (戸警察)
- のX　　　　　　　うえよしひろ： 005 (上嘉浩¹・上義啓¹・上吉弘¹・上良弘¹・上嘉弘¹)
- のX　　　　　　　　　やすまろ： 005 (安万侶¹・安麻呂³・安萬侶¹)
- のX　　　　　　　　うえたつお： 005 (上達夫¹・上竜夫¹・上辰雄¹・上達男¹・上達雄¹)
- のX　　　　　　　　　　えらぶ： 005 (永良部)
- のX　　　　　　　だてまちしも： 005 (館町下)
- のX　　　　　　　　うえかずお： 005 (上和雄¹・上一男¹・上和郎¹・上一夫¹・上一雄¹)
- のX　　　　　　みやちゅうおう： 004 (宮中央)
- のX　　　　　　　しんやちょう： 004 (新屋町)
- のX　　　　　　　　　かぐやま： 004 (香久山²・香具山²)
- のX　　　　　　　みやししょう： 004 (宮市消)
- のX　　　　　　　　みやかんい： 004 (宮簡易)
- のX　　　　　　みやびょういん： 004 (宮病院)
- のX　　　　　ひがしのみささぎ： 004 (東陵)
- のX　　　　　しょうちょうりつ： 004 (庄町立)
- のX　　　　　　　　うえしんじ： 004 (上信治¹・上真二¹・上伸治¹・上慎二¹)
- のX　　　　　　　　へかいどう： 004 (戸街道)
- のX　　　　うらしょうがっこう： 004 (浦小学校)
- のX　　　　　　　　なかつくに： 004 (中国)
- のX　　　　　　　　うえまさお： 004 (上雅央¹・上正夫¹・上雅雄¹・上雅夫¹)
- のX　　　　　　　うえまさゆき： 004 (上正幸¹・上正之¹・上将行¹・上雅之¹)
- のX　　　　　みやちょうひがし： 004 (宮町東)
- のX　　　　　　　　　やしりつ： 004 (屋市立)
- のX　　　　　　　　うえこうじ： 004 (上浩司¹・上晃二¹・上公二¹・上幸治¹)
- のX　　　　　　　　　むしまろ： 004 (虫麻呂)
- のX　　　　　　　　　こうじけ： 004 (小路家)
- のX　　　　くちちゅうがっこう： 004 (口中学校)
- のX　　　　　　　うえこういち： 004 (上晃一¹・上紘一¹・上幸一¹・上浩一¹)
- のX　　　　うえしょうがっこう： 004 (上小学校)
- のX　　　　　　　　みかどふゆ： 004 (御門冬)
- のX　　　　　　　したとしやす： 004 (下俊保¹・下俊泰¹・下利恭¹・下利安¹)
- のX　　　　　　　もとじんじゃ： 004 (本神社)
- のX　　　　　　　　　うえみつ： 004 (上光³・上満¹)
- のX　　　　　　　　　くろまろ： 003 (黒麻呂)
- のX　　　　　　　せきけいさつ： 003 (関警察)
- のX　　　　　　　うえまさひろ： 003 (上雅博¹・上正広¹・上正大¹)
- のX　　　　　　　　うえてつお： 003 (上鉄勇¹・上哲夫¹・上哲央¹)
- のX　　　　もとしょうがっこう： 003 (本小学校)
- のX　　　　　　　うえだいすけ： 003 (上大佑¹・上大輔¹・上大助¹)
- のX　　　　　　　えちょうやす： 003 (江町安)
- のX　　　　　　　うえけいいち： 003 (上圭一¹・上敬一¹・上恵一¹)
- のX　　　　　　　　　　むつの： 003 (陸奥)
- のX　　　　　　　もりじんじゃ： 003 (森神社)
- のX　　　　　　　したひろゆき： 003 (下浩之¹・下博之¹・下浩行¹)
- のX　　　　　　　　　うえゆか： 003 (上ユカ¹・上ゆか¹・上優佳¹)
- のX　　　　　　　　でがくえん： 003 (出学園)
- のX　　　　　　　みややまぐち： 003 (宮山口)
- のX　　　　　　　　みやくけん： 003 (宮区検)
- のX　　　　　　　うえまさはる： 003 (上正春¹・上正治¹・上正晴¹)
- のX　　　　　　　　うえしろう： 003 (上四郎²・上士朗¹)
- のX　　　　　　　　おかこふん： 003 (岡古墳)
- のX　　　　　　みやちょうふく： 003 (宮町福)
- のX　　　　　　　　うえのまさ： 003 (上当²・上正¹)
- のX　　　　　　　みやけいさつ： 003 (宮警察)
- のX　　　　　　　うえひろかず： 003 (上博和¹・上博一¹・上弘一¹)
- のX　　　　　　　　　うえよし： 003 (上よし²・上ヨシ¹)
- のX　　　　　　　　うえたかお： 003 (上孝雄¹・上貴朗¹・上隆雄¹)
- のX　　　　　　　　　こうじあ： 003 (小路上)
- のX　　　　　　　　　すくなま： 003 (宿那麻¹・宿奈麻²)
- のX　　　　　えしょうがっこう： 003 (江小学校)
- のX　　　　　　みやちょうかみ： 003 (宮町上)
- のX　　　　　　　　きじんじゃ： 003 (木神社)
- のX　　　　　　　　みやしけい： 003 (宮市警)
- のX　　　　　　　うえたかゆき： 003 (上堯之²・上隆之¹)
- のX　　　　　　　だてまちかわ： 003 (館町川)
- のX　　　　　　　さきおんせん： 003 (崎温泉)
- のX　　　　　　　　おじんじゃ： 003 (尾神社²・男神社¹)
- のX　　　　　　　みねじんじゃ： 003 (峯神社²・峰神社¹)
- のX　　　　　　　　　いらつめ： 003 (郎女)
- のX　　　　　　　　うえゆうき： 003 (上雄幾¹・上裕貴¹・上祐輝¹)
- のX　　　　　　　みちおおはし： 003 (道大橋)
- のX　　　しょうしょうがっこう： 003 (荘小学校¹・庄小学校²)
- のX　　　　　　　　みみはらの： 003 (耳原)
- のX　　　　　　　べちょうりつ： 003 (辺町立)
- のX　　　　　　　　　みつよし： 003 (光栄¹・光能¹・満快¹)
- のX　　　　　　　　みやどうろ： 003 (宮道路)
- のX　　　　かみしょうがっこう： 003 (上小学校¹・神小学校²)
- のX　　　　　　おかのみささぎ： 003 (丘陵²・崗陵¹)
- のX　　　　　　　　みなかぬし： 003 (御中主)
- のX　　　　　　　　うえとしお： 003 (上敏夫¹・上鋭夫¹・上俊夫¹)

## In front, Xの...

**Length 1**

- Xの　　　　い： 763 (亥¹・飯⁸・井⁷⁰⁴・伊⁹・祖²・藺¹・斐²・比²・肄¹・娃¹・炊²⁷・位⁴・易¹)
- Xの　　　わら： 647 (原)
- Xの　　　　き： 405 (黄²・木²⁴⁴・城³¹・喜²・来⁶・岐¹⁴・芸⁶・紀⁷⁶・槻¹・貴³・酒¹・伎⁴・鬼³・企²・季²・吉¹・置⁴・杵¹・材¹・樹¹)
- Xの　みなもと： 298 (源)
- Xの　　　いち： 230 (一²⁰⁴・市²¹・櫟⁴・壱¹)
- Xの　　　　み： 220 (箕¹¹⁵・水⁷・三⁴・美¹⁰・身⁶・実⁷・江⁹・見⁵²・海⁴・味¹・明¹・看¹・稔¹・農¹・績¹)
- Xの　　　　つ： 193 (津²⁶・⁷・奥¹²・都¹⁴⁸)
- Xの　　　　え： 178 (榎¹⁰⁰・江⁴⁶・風²・荏²・絵⁵・枝³・吉⁵・兄⁸・衛⁴・殖¹・恵¹・家¹)
- Xの　　　　か： 170 (神³・上¹・鹿⁶⁸・ケ¹・香⁴・彼⁵⁹・化¹・迦¹・嘉¹・下¹⁰・賀¹⁰・加¹・鳥³・歌²・訶¹・花¹・珂¹・箇¹・家¹)
- Xの　　たいら： 153 (平)
- Xの　　　にし： 139 (西)
- Xの　　　　ひ： 128 (桧¹¹・日⁵⁵・樋¹¹・檜²¹・緋²・火⁵・氷²・簸²・比¹⁴・飛¹・旭¹・陽¹・妃¹・肥¹)
- Xの　　　　に： 123 (二¹⁰⁰・新³・似⁷・邇¹⁰・弐²・丹¹)
- Xの　　　やま： 118 (山)
- Xの　　　　し： 116 (之²⁴・四²¹・師⁶・信⁴⁰・紫⁶・司²・氏¹・巳²・侍¹・志²・磯¹・石⁴・斯¹・旨¹・子¹・死¹・治¹・士¹)
- Xの　　　　べ： 107 (部⁵³・倍⁴⁹・辺⁴・戸¹)
- Xの　　　こう： 106 (鴻⁵⁴・神³⁶・香⁵・高⁹・鵠¹・亨¹)
- Xの　　　　た： 098 (田⁸²・多¹⁰・咫²・タ¹・駄¹・楽¹・太¹)
- Xの　　　　と： 095 (外³⁸・砥³・渡³・富⁴・鳥²・戸¹⁶・登⁴・門⁵・土¹²・斗²・刀²・度¹・人²・都¹)
- Xの　　　　の： 093 (濃¹¹・¹・篦⁵・野⁷³・乃²・埜¹)
- Xの　　　　お： 090 (生²・男⁷・尾⁶⁸・武¹・苧²・夫¹・麻¹・乃²・面²・雄³・保¹)
- Xの　　　はち： 090 (鉢²・蜂¹・八⁸⁷)
- Xの　　　　や： 090 (野⁵⁸・屋¹⁹・矢⁹・耶¹・夜¹・谷²)
- Xの　　　しも： 080 (下)
- Xの　　　いん： 077 (院⁵³・因²³・尹¹)
- Xの　　　なか： 073 (中⁶⁹・仲⁴)
- Xの　　　はら： 071 (原⁶⁹・腹²)
- Xの　　　とみ： 071 (富⁴²・臣²⁹)
- Xの　　　　ゆ： 070 (湯⁴⁴・柚²⁶)
- Xの　　　かく： 067 (角⁶⁶・覚¹)
- Xの　　　　せ： 066 (瀬¹⁶・妹²⁸・背²・勢¹⁸・兄¹・施¹)
- Xの　　　　こ： 065 (金⁴・木²⁹・神²・香¹・子¹⁰・粉²・海鼠²・古¹⁰・胡¹・児¹・鈷¹・小¹・籠¹)
- Xの　たちばな： 064 (橘)
- Xの　　　　が： 061 (ケ¹・賀²⁵・峨¹・鹿²・河⁴・我¹⁴・³・日⁸・迦¹・箇¹・神¹)
- Xの　　　かみ： 060 (上⁵⁰・神⁹・守¹)
- Xの　　　　ご： 059 (児²・五¹⁶・後²⁵・碁¹・護³・庫³・互¹・胡¹・御¹・子³・午¹・戸¹・檎¹)
- Xの　　　　ま： 055 (馬¹⁷・士¹・間⁶・摩¹³・磨⁵・部¹・麻⁹・麗¹・蟇¹・万¹)
- Xの　　　　だ： 054 (田⁴⁸・騨³・太²・陀¹)
- Xの　　　たけ： 053 (竹⁵²・建¹)
- Xの　　あぶら： 049 (油)
- Xの　　　しお： 049 (塩⁴³・潮⁶)
- Xの　　　とも： 048 (伴⁴⁴・友³・鞆¹)
- Xの　　　　ほ： 047 (保²²・穂¹⁵・帆³・火⁷)
- Xの　　　　わ： 047 (訪⁹・杷¹・輪⁴・波¹⁸・羽⁸・房³・方¹・和²・破¹)
- Xの　　　いし： 046 (石)
- Xの　　　つき： 046 (槻²⁶・築¹・月¹⁹)
- Xの　　　かわ： 045 (川³²・河¹³)
- Xの　　　　じ： 044 (子²・地¹・路³・士²⁰・寺³・氏¹・治³・師⁴・自¹・事³・道²・時¹)
- Xの　　　　う： 043 (鵜¹⁷・府⁹・宇⁵・生³・武⁵・卯⁴)
- Xの　　　くす： 040 (楠³⁹・樟¹)
- Xの　　　あめ： 039 (雨¹³・天²⁶)
- Xの　　　かき： 039 (柿²⁸・蠣¹・硴¹・垣⁵・籬²・墻¹・蛎¹)
- Xの　　　いけ： 038 (池)
- Xの　　　さん： 036 (三³⁴・山¹・産¹)
- Xの　　みやこ： 036 (都)
- Xの　　　　な： 035 (七¹⁶・名¹⁰・儺¹・那²・和¹・女¹・奈³・ナ¹)
- Xの　　ひがし： 034 (東)
- Xの　　　　ち： 033 (茅⁵・刀¹・遅²・内⁹・市⁵・智⁵・地²・知²・池¹・乳¹)
- Xの　　やなぎ： 033 (柳)
- Xの　　　　め： 033 (女⁷・目⁸・売⁹・馬¹・米⁶・芽¹・眼¹)
- Xの　　　　く： 033 (久⁴・工²・来³・九²⁴)
- Xの　　　あい： 033 (相²⁷・藍³・間¹・合¹・愛¹)
- Xの　　　たか： 032 (鷹²⁸・高⁴)
- Xの　　　さか： 032 (坂³¹・阪¹)
- Xの　　　あま： 032 (天³⁰・海人¹・海¹)
- Xの　　　みや： 032 (宮)
- Xの　　　おき： 031 (興⁴・沖²⁷)
- Xの　　　しま： 030 (島²⁰・嶋¹⁰)
- Xの　　　まつ： 029 (松)
- Xの　　　すみ： 029 (住¹⁶・角⁵・隅⁵・墨³)
- Xの　　　あや： 029 (綾²⁷・彩²)
- Xの　　　うち： 027 (内)
- Xの　　　とう： 027 (鶇¹・唐⁵・当³・東⁸・塔⁵・頭³・滕¹・等¹)
- Xの　　　もの： 026 (物)
- Xの　　　　ば： 026 (場²・葉⁶・波¹⁰・庭²・馬²・羽³・端¹)
- Xの　　　ぜん： 025 (前²²・染¹・膳²)
- Xの　　　　す： 025 (洲¹⁰・簾³・簀²・須⁹・素¹)
- Xの　　　みち： 025 (道¹⁹・路⁴・盈²)
- Xの　　じょう： 024 (城⁶・聖¹・上¹・条¹³・庄¹・丈¹・條¹)
- Xの　　　うえ： 022 (上)
- Xの　　　しち： 022 (七)
- Xの　　　　び： 021 (日⁴・毘²・備¹²・傍¹・斐¹・比¹)
- Xの　　　しな： 021 (階²⁰・科¹)
- Xの　　　くま： 021 (熊⁸・隈¹³)
- Xの　　　かん： 020 (神⁹・金¹・甲²・鑑¹・寒²・漢¹・巻¹・環¹・寛¹・間¹)

**Length 2**

- Xの　　　　　ふじわら： 627 (藤原)
- Xの　　　　　　　うつ： 144 (宇津²・宇都¹⁴²)
- Xの　　　　　　　あべ： 052 (安倍³⁷・阿倍¹²・阿部¹・安部²)
- Xの　　　　　　　みや： 042 (宮野)
- Xの　　　　　　おおえ： 034 (大兄⁸・大江²⁴・大枝¹・大家¹)
- Xの　　　　　　おおい： 030 (大井³・大炊²⁷)
- Xの　　　　　おおとも： 028 (大伴²⁶・大友²)
- Xの　　　　　　ふしみ： 024 (伏見)
- Xの　　　　　なかとみ： 023 (中臣)
- Xの　　　どおりあぶら： 023 (通油)
- Xの　　　　　　のうえ： 020 (上¹⁹・之上¹)
- Xの　　　　　　　みほ： 020 (美保¹⁹・御火¹)
- Xの　　　　　　　ふじ： 020 (富士)
- Xの　　　　どおりとみ： 020 (通富)
- Xの　　　　　きよはら： 020 (清原)
- Xの　　　どおりやなぎ： 018 (通柳)
- Xの　　　　どおりにし： 018 (通西)
- Xの　　　　　　　のべ： 016 (部¹⁵・辺¹)
- Xの　　　　　いしかわ： 016 (石川)
- Xの　　　どおりひがし： 016 (通東)
- Xの　　　　　　さえき： 015 (佐伯)
- Xの　　　　　　　かや： 015 (萱野¹⁴・蚊屋¹)
- Xの　　　　　たかしな： 015 (高階)
- Xの　　　　　　　なか： 014 (な彼¹²・那珂¹・那賀¹)
- Xの　　　　　　　おの： 014 (小野)
- Xの　　　　　　　じひ： 013 (治比)
- Xの　　　　　　　むつ： 013 (陸奥¹²・六¹)
- Xの　　　　　　がわら： 013 (原)
- Xの　　　　　　　みの： 013 (美濃⁶・三野⁷)
- Xの　　　　　　ひがし： 012 (東之)
- Xの　　　　　　いずも： 012 (出雲)
- Xの　　　　　もんいん： 011 (門院)
- Xの　　　　　　　けの： 011 (毛野)
- Xの　　　　　　　かも： 011 (賀茂⁸・加茂²・迦毛¹)
- Xの　　　　　なかはら： 011 (中原)
- Xの　　　　　　　そが： 011 (蘇我¹⁰・曽我¹)
- Xの　　　　　　　きび： 010 (吉備)
- Xの　　　　　ちょうい： 010 (町井⁹・町飯¹)
- Xの　　　　　　なにわ： 010 (難波)
- Xの　　　　どおりあや： 010 (通綾)
- Xの　　　　　　　こせ： 010 (巨勢)
- Xの　　　　　　　すわ： 010 (諏訪⁹・諏方¹)
- Xの　　　　　　　あわ： 010 (阿波⁷・安房³)

**Length 3**

- Xの　　　　　　　　さかのうえ： 015 (坂上)
- Xの　　　　　　　　　もののべ： 015 (物部)
- Xの　　　　　　　　　　たじひ： 013 (多治比)
- Xの　　　　　　　おおなかとみ： 013 (大中臣)
- Xの　　　　　　　　　すがわら： 013 (菅原)
- Xの　　　　　　　　　　つけの： 010 (毛野)
- Xの　　　　　　とうさっきゅう： 009 (頭作九)
- Xの　　　　　　　とちょうゆき： 008 (戸町雪)
- Xの　　　　　　まちどおりにし： 007 (町通西)
- Xの　　　　　　　　　のおおえ： 006 (大兄)
- Xの　　　　　　　じどおりとみ： 006 (寺通富²・路通富⁴)
- Xの　　　　　　　　　すみのえ： 006 (住吉⁵・墨江¹)

**Length 4**

- Xの　　　　　　　　　むとうさっきゅう： 009 (無頭作九)
- Xの　　　　　　　　　　せとちょうゆき： 008 (瀬戸町雪)
- Xの　　　　　　　　　　　　しもつけの： 007 (下毛野)

**Length 5**

- Xの　　　　　　　　　　　　おおせとちょうゆき： 008 (大瀬戸町雪)

Answer (score 2):

(I think 中大兄皇子 was actually なかの おおえの みこ more precisely, なかつおほへのみこ [nakatu-opopeno-miko])

I believe they couldn't if it's off from common patterns just like people today. As for the examples above, I believe they could, because they are a pattern that naturally makes sense (中大兄皇子・三宮； さんみや wouldn't make sense) or a common pattern (班田収授法).

Comment: Thanks.  I guess my question is: (1) do most old names and words like this fall into common patterns?  And (2) can one list the "main" common patterns?  One seems to be that there is often a の before certain titles such as 皇子, 皇女, but not 天皇, and I guess there is often a の between clan and given names.   For instance, what is the common pattern you say 班田収授法 is a part of?  Is it things ending in 法 or is it part of something more general?

Comment: (1) I guess so, though I have no evidences. It's natural for people to do what seems natural to them. なかのおおえのみこ means "the second crown prince/-ss" and I think they called him so because he was. (2) I'm not sure what's main but I'd be able to say family names in a certain era have の etc. And, is it just natural that Chinese (international) titles of Tenno, which you call that of 天皇 don't include の while domestic titles, which you call that of 皇子, 皇女do? And, I think I often hear ～の法 in archaic titles of codes.