# Why is it 悪魔 and not 悪の魔?

Tags: particle-の, compounds, modification

Shouldn't  there be の to signify that 悪 modifies 魔? It seems to be a one word and not a phrase, how do we know if a double kanji is such a single word and not two separate ones when reading a text?

Comment: You might as well be asking, "why is it horsepower?" instead of "power of a horse"?

Comment: @A.Ellett You wouldn't happen to know the answer to that question, would you?

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga This is one of those situations where I just learn 悪魔 as a vocabulary item.  I don't think of it as two words.

Comment: Regarding these sorts of situations, as you learn more vocabulary, you will be able to parse such things much easily.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27485/7810

Comment: also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23447/3295 (in particular the bit about 彼女)

Answer (score 5):

> Shouldn't there be の to signify that 悪 modifies 魔?

No.  This term was borrowed in its entirety from Chinese, as a single term.

Borrowing aside, two-character compounds are generally parsed as single terms -- even those coined in Japan.

> It seems to be a one word and not a phrase, how do we know if a double kanji is such a single word and not two separate ones when reading a text?

Fundamentally, one learns to recognize such things over the course of time in studying the language.

To better answer your question, as above, it's a good bet that many (most?) kanji pairs that don't have kana in between are probably compounds.  Many (most?) such compounds are also read using the *on'yomi*, which is useful information when trying to either pronounce these terms or look them up in a dictionary.