# Why is the "NO" pronounced but not written in 山手, 井上 , 木下?

Tags: words, readings

The names are read Yamanote, Inoue and Kinoshita. Where is the NO written? Is NO the only pronunciation that is used but omitted when writing names?　Does it only happen when NO is used? Apparently, its only used in a handful of names, pronounced but not written. Any explanation would be helpful.

Comment: related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/why-did-%e3%81%ae-disappear-from-%e5%b1%b1%e6%89%8b-but-in-%e5%be%a1%e8%8c%b6%e3%83%8e%e6%b0%b4-its-in-katakana

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23428/9831

Comment: @Chocolate , wow apparently it was more common in the past. Yama No Shita became Yamashita!